# javax web service client array

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to call a webservice which expects an array as parameter but I've no idea how to do that, I have no wsdl and I'd like to use javax to do that.

```
    String operation = "TheOperationName";    
    String urn = "TheWebService";
    String destination = "http://my-server/something.php";

    // First create the connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection connection = soapConnFactory.createConnection();


      // Next, create the actual message
      MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
      SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

      SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
      SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
      envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENC", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
        // Create and populate the body
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

     // Create the main element and namespace
        SOAPElement operationItem = body.addChildElement(
                envelope.createQName(operation, "ns1"));
```

//Here I'm lost, I should create an array

param0 SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Struct[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"

which contains my items array

```
        SOAPElement itemElement = myarray.addChildElement("item");

        // Add parameters
        itemElement.addChildElement("ID_Bug").addTextNode("ID");
        itemElement.addChildElement("ID_Release").addTextNode("RELEASE");

        // Save the message
        message.saveChanges();

        // Send the message and get the reply
        SOAPMessage reply = connection.call(message, destination);
        reply.toString();

        // Close the connection           
        connection.close();
```

any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: Without WSDL, how do you know what input you need to give and what output to expect ?

Comment: the programmer behind the webservice I call told me which parameters he expects (an array containing "items" where items is a class with some fields) and before you ask, no he cannot create the wsdl for me